# Why doesn't Firebase send a message with Advanced Options?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM messaging service in my Android app. It is sending the notification quick and fast.

Everyday I am sending One message to my app installed users using:

**IN ADVANCED OPTIONS**

```
Title

Key1                       Value1

Key2                       Value2

Key3                       Value3

Key4                       Value4

Key5                       Value5
```

and so on.

This format was working fine in the past few months. For this month, the words on messages are not sending with more than 3 key-value pairs.

If I entered 3 key-value pairs, the message will send. If it's more than that, the notification is not sending and shows the error message

```
MESSAGE TOO BIG
```

My Questions:

- Why is it happening for this month only? Were there any data limits set?
- If they are setting data limits, why are they allowing 'n' number of key-value pairs?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it happening for this month only? Were there any data limits set?

If you refer to the [Official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> A notification message is the more lightweight option, with a 2KB limit and a predefined set of user-visible keys. **Data messages let developers send up to 4KB of custom key-value pairs**.

---

> If they are setting data limits, why are they allowing 'n' number of key-value pairs?

Pretty sure that the reason they're allowing you to provide your own key-value pairs in Firebase Console is that they trust that you'll be abiding/checking on that rule yourself. The `MESSAGE TOO BIG` error message is just the warning that you've reached it.

However, if you're pretty sure that your payload is less than 4KB and it still doesn't send, then that's for sure out of the intended behavior. With that, you should go ahead and contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).